# How do I call the servers recursively and efficiently until I get the proper response back?

Tags: java, recursion

I have two flag currently. One is `remoteFlag` and other is `secondaryFlag`. By default both of them are true, customer can change them if they want to change while they are making a call to our Application. So possible combination that can happen is -

```
remoteFlag       secondaryFlag

true             true
true             false
false            false
false            true
```

By default it is always true and true.

I am supposed to make a HTTP Call to our servers (all the servers are Ubunutu machines). Suppose below are my servers with fully qualified hostname corresponding to `hostname -f` in unix.

```
String hostname1 = hostname1;
String hostname2 = hostname2;

String hostname3 = hostname3;
String hostname4 = hostname4;
```

I have couple of cases which I am supposed to do as described below -

1. Suppose if the `remoteFlag` and `secondaryFlag` both are `true` then I
   am supposed to hit all the above servers one by one until we get the
   response back from the servers. Meaning suppose `hostname1` is down
   so we won't get any response back from that servers and it will
   throw an exception so then we will go to `hostname2` to fetch the
   same data but suppose if `hostname2` is also down, then we will go
   `hostname3` to fetch the data but if suppose `hostname3` is also
   down then we will go to `hostname4` to fetch the data. But if any of
   the servers is able to give the response back then we will return
   the call by making proper response saying that we have got the data.
   And if none of the servers are able to give the respone back then we
   will make an error response saying all the servers are down.
2. Now if the `remoteFlag` is `true` and `secondaryFlag` is `false`, then
   we will only go to `hostname1` and `hostname3`. If `hostname1` is
   down, then we will go to `hostname3` to get the response. If both of
   them are down, then we will make an ERROR response saying servers
   are down.
3. Now if the `remoteFlag` is `false` and `secondaryFlag` is `false`, then
   we will only go to `hostname1`, that's all. If `hostname1` is down,
   then we will make an ERROR response saying servers are down.
4. Now if the `remoteFlag` is `false` and `secondaryFlag` is `true`, then
   we will only go to `hostname1` and `hostname2`, that's all. If
   `hostname1` is down, then we will go to `hostname2` to get the
   response. If both of them are down, then we will make an ERROR
   response saying servers are down.

By down I mean servers are not up, so that's why they are not responding. I tried on one of the servers which was down, `RestTemplate` throws an exception if I try to hit that server.

Below is my code so far which only works for if the `remoteFlag` and `secondaryFlag` both are true but again it doesn't look to me good code as I am simply repeating stuff in the below code. I am not sure how do I keep on calling recursively the servers if any one of them are down. But if any one of them are up and got proper response then return the call by making a SUCCESS response with the actual data that I have got.

Below is

```
public class ClientTask implements Callable<ClientResponse> {

    public ClientTask(ClientKey clientKeys) {
        this.clientKeys = clientKeys;
    }

    @Override
    public ClientResponse call() throws Exception {
        ....

        boolean remoteFlag = clientKeys.isRemoteFlag();
        boolean secondaryFlag = clientKeys.isSecondaryFlag();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response = null;
        ...

        String hostname1 = hostname1;
        String hostname2 = hostname2;

        String hostname3 = hostname3;
        String hostname4 = hostname4;

        // first use case when both are true
        if(remoteFlag && secondaryFlag) {
            if(hostname1 != null) {
                try {
                    String url = generateURL(hostname1);            
                    response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

                    return new ClientResponse(response, ClientError.NONE, ClientStatus.SUCCESS);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); // use logger
                }
            }            
            // hostname1 is down
            if(response == null && hostname2 != null) {
                try {
                    String url = generateURL(hostname2);            
                    response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

                    return new ClientResponse(response, ClientError.NONE, ClientStatus.SUCCESS);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); // use logger
                }
            }
            // hostname1 and 2 both are down
            if(response == null && hostname3 != null) {
                try {
                    String url = generateURL(hostname3);            
                    response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

                    return new ClientResponse(response, ClientError.NONE, ClientStatus.SUCCESS);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); // use logger
                }
            }
            // hostname1, 2, 3 are down
            if(response == null && hostname4 != null) {
                try {
                    String url = generateURL(hostname4);            
                    response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

                    return new ClientResponse(response, ClientError.NONE, ClientStatus.SUCCESS);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); // use logger
                }
            }
        }

        // not sure how to add other use case logic here as well properly
    }

    /**
     * Method to generate the url to hit the servers. 
     * 
     */ 
    private String generateURL(final String hostname) {
        StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer();
        url.append("http://" + hostname + ":8080/user?userId=" + clientKeys.getUserId() + "&page_id=" + clientKeys.getPageId());

        Set<Entry<String, String>> params = clientKeys.getAttributeMap().entrySet();

        for(Entry<String, String> e : params){
            url.append("&" + e.getKey());
            url.append("=" + e.getValue());
        }

        return url.toString();
    }
}
```

**ProblemStatement:-**

In the above code, I am simply repeating stuff all the time, not sure how do I recursively keep on calling the servers until I get the response back. And also how do I fit other use case as well in the above code. Initially I was thinking to add same if block for other use case. Then I thought my whole code will be filled up with if block only.

Any thoughts how can I solve this problem efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of boiler plates in your code. You can easily avoid them by only filling a list of hosts in your if statements. Afterwards you iterate over that list:

```
List<String> hostnames = new ArrayList<>();
if(remoteFlag && secondaryFlag) {
    hostnames.add(hostname1);
    hostnames.add(hostname2);

} else if …

for (String hostname : hostnames) {
    if(hostname == null) {
        continue;

    }
    try {
        String url = generateURL(hostname1);            
        response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        break;

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(); // use logger

    }
}
if (response == null) {
    // do error handling

}
return new ClientResponse(response, ClientError.NONE, ClientStatus.SUCCESS);
```

---

Personally I would prefer another solution. Build a component which expresses the state transitions and link those components:

```
public class FallbackCall() {

    private String hostname;

    private String secondaryHostname;

    private FallbackQuery next;

    public ClientResponse call(boolean remote, boolean secondary) {
        ClientResponse response = getResponse(hostname);
        if (response == null && secondary) {
            reponse = getResponse(secondaryHostname);

        }
        if (response == null && remote) {
            reponse = next.call(remote, secondary);

        }
        return response;
    }

    private ClientResponse getResponse(String hostname) {
        // your boiler plate
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. For now I would go with your first suggestion.. In your example if all the servers are down, then how would I make an ERROR response and send it back to customer? Currently it won't make anything..

Comment: Simply throw an exception if the last result is null.

Comment: I should throw and check my last result after the for loop.. Correct? Bcoz that's where I can see my last result..

Comment: Yes, I updated the first solution to reflect your new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to extract the retrieval into another method (perhaps even "static"), like so

```
// I don't recognize your library...
public ClientResponse call(String hostname) throws Exception {
  if (hostname == null) {
    return null;
  }
  // You might also make generateURL static 
  String url = generateURL(hostname);
  String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url,
      String.class);
  if (response == null) { // add more logic here to test your response.
     return null;
  }
  return new ClientResponse(response,
      ClientError.NONE, ClientStatus.SUCCESS);
}
```

Then you can pass in your url(s) one by one, until you get a good response. Like this,

```
// String hostname1 = hostname1;
// String hostname2 = hostname2;
// String hostname3 = hostname3;
// String hostname4 = hostname4;
if(remoteFlag && secondaryFlag) {
  ClientResponse response = call(hostname1);
  // != null is one test. However you test the response is valid.
  if (response != null) return response;
  response = call(hostname2);
  if (response != null) return response;
  response = call(hostname3);
  if (response != null) return response;
  return call(hostname4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott. Sorry if I was not clear.. The above code I have is in the class which implements CallableTask so the call method is coming from there.. I am supposed to do all these stuffs in that call method. I can make another method to execute the URL and make the response but how do I call that method recursively everythime?

Comment: You don't call it recursively, first call with hostname1 ... is result != null, if so return it... next call with hostname2 ... is result != null; until hostname4... return result. And that method can call other methods! Especially static methods.

Comment: Can you provide an example basis on my above scenario. I am confuse how we can do this without using recursive here. Any help will be appreciated.. Thanks..